# How To Loop Through Elements & Count Numbers?

Tags: javascript, loops, count, numbers

Let's say I have these spans that contain numbers I am trying to fetch and count ...

```
<span class = "apples">9 apples</span>
<span class = "apples">7 apples</span>
<span class = "apples">3 apples</span>
<span class = "apples">6 apples</span>
<span class = "apples">11 apples</span>
```

How would I call on the browser to fetch the number of apples in each span and then return a total number?

I only know basic javascript so

I would think Id have to loop through the span elements and find whichever one has the className "apples". 
Ha, and well ... I don't know what to do after that for this particular situation.

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: see [document.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName)

Comment: Split it to 2 separate and independent tasks: 1. how to fetch spans with a given class name. And how to fetch its text. 2. How to retrieve a number from a string in a form `"N apples"`

Comment: It would be good if you can show what have you attempted so far

Comment: Using @ArunPJohny thought ;) `alert(document.getElementsByClassName("apples").length);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this!

1. store all span elements with the class apples in a var and setup the total var for later

   var apples = document.querySelectorAll('span.apples'),

   total = 0;
2. loop through the array and use the parseInt function to get the number out of the textContent of each element, and then add that value to our total

   for (var i = 0; i < apples.length; i++) {

   ```
       total += parseInt(apples[i].textContent, 10);
   ```

   };
3. do something with total

   console.log(total);

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = document.getElementsByClassName("apples"),
len = obj.length,
total = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
total+=parseInt(obj[i].innerHTML);
```